# QT Design Studio project doesnt work on QT Creator

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qt-quick

I am currently working on a UI and I came open this issue with QT Creator.

When I try to create QtQuick apps on Creator, i get this error message.

> 22:36:00: Starting C:\Qt\6.1.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmlscene.exe -I
> C:/Users/fatih/Documents/untitled7/imports -I
> C:/Users/fatih/Documents/untitled7/asset_imports
> C:/Users/fatih/Documents/untitled7/untitled7.qml...
> file:///C:/Users/fatih/Documents/untitled7/untitled7.qml:9 Type
> Screen01 unavailable
> file:///C:/Users/fatih/Documents/untitled7/Screen01.ui.qml:-1 Type
> Constants unavailable
> file:///C:/Users/fatih/Documents/untitled7/imports/untitled7/Constants.qml:8
> Invalid property assignment: "name" is a read-only property

I am trying to fix this issue but I couldn't. How can I?

Answer (score -1):

Okay I found the answer

Go to QT Creator Preferences (Menu Bar | Tools > Options)

Select QT Quick Option (Options headings - left side).

Click the QT Quick Designer tab.

Under QML Emulation Layer grouping, select "Use QML Emulation Layer that is built with selected QT".

No need to choose a path, just click Ok.